# How do I click on this check box using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I would like to select this checkbox using selenium

```
<input type="checkbox" name="rg" onchange="onCheckReg(this)" id="beauty_perfume_screening__c" value="beauty_perfume_screening__c" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="check-button-Beauty Perfume Screening check-group-header">
```

I tried finding by xpath an by id but always get the error unable to locate element

```
wd.find_element_by_id("beauty_perfume_screening__c").click()
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Could you share the link to the website?

Comment: And share a minimal reproducible example of your code.

Comment: @Farzan Ali Khan It is possible that this element is on some frame located, then you need first switch to frame and then search for it.

Comment: I can but it cant be accessed without the proper proxy. if you need more information like the source code of this particular page I can provide that

Comment: Yes it is inside a frame

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi can you elaborate on how to switch to the Frame

Comment: @FarzanAliKhan search on stack there is plenty answers for this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use xpath

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='rg']").click()
```

and recommended is to use one of the wait methods -

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located(By.XPATH, "//input[@name='rg']")
```

For selecting iframe -

```
root1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe")
driver.switch_to.frame(root1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To click on the element with text as **save** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `id`:

  ```
  wd.find_element_by_id("beauty_perfume_screening__c").click()
  ```
- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  wd.find_element_by_css_selector("input#beauty_perfume_screening__c[name='rg'][value='beauty_perfume_screening__c']").click()
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  wd.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='beauty_perfume_screening__c' and @name='rg'][@value='beauty_perfume_screening__c']").click()
  ```

Ideally, to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `ID`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(wd, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "beauty_perfume_screening__c"))).click()
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(wd, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#beauty_perfume_screening__c[name='rg'][value='beauty_perfume_screening__c']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(wd, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='beauty_perfume_screening__c' and @name='rg'][@value='beauty_perfume_screening__c']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> **Important**: Incase the element is within an `<iframe>` you have to switch to the `<iframe>` first.
>
> You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:
>
> - [Ways to deal with #document under iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53203417/ways-to-deal-with-document-under-iframe)
> - [Switch to an iframe through Selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44834358/switch-to-an-iframe-through-selenium-and-python/44847390#44847390)

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions on [NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47993443/selenium-selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-when-using-chrome/47995294#47995294) in:

- [selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element while trying to click Next button with selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50315587/selenium-common-exceptions-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-una/50315715#50315715)
- [selenium in python : NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53441658/selenium-in-python-nosuchelementexception-message-no-such-element-unable-to/53442511#53442511)